# I am not understanding why this is happening with empty php variables

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I try to do this:

```
if ($var !== ""){
    $message = "whatever";
}
```

But end up having to do this:

```
if ($var == ""){
    //do nothing
} else {
    $message = "whatever";
}
```

Why does that happen? Shouldn't both of those mean the same thing?

Comment: so, how do i make the first one work? i want to write less code, not more code.

Comment: Whats value of `$var`?

Comment: If you just want to check if its `not empty` ... you could just do `if (!empty($var)) { }` ... but that will skip `0` (zero) as well... which to you may sound like its not empty, but zero actually means empty ;)

Comment: I dont see why the first does not work, it works for me. What value is in `$var` that is causing you odd results

Comment: i spit it out and there is nothing. empty.

Comment: so when filled do something. if empty do nothing. that's what i need. this ended up working..... if (!empty($var)) {}

Comment: Wondering if your $var actually had `NULL` in it, instead of just an empty string cast var. Did it come from a db field? Did you ever set $var first? Just curious where that came from.

Comment: i does come from db.  $var = $result['column_name'];

Comment: and the line above that line is: $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'"), MYSQL_ASSOC);

Comment: `$var != ""` will produce the "expected" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!=` and `==` are opposites (non-strict comparison operators).

`!==` and `===` are opposites (strict comparison operators, where the value must match what you are comparing exactly).

If you use `!=` instead of `!==`, your code should work.  But:

- You should understand what the actual value of your variable is - it's not an empty string.  You can use `print_r( $var );` to see it.
- It's better to use the strict comparison operators `===` and `!==`, because they have well-defined behavior that is easier to remember and debug.

Answer (score 1):

As `$var` is really `string` just use:

```
if ($var){//any non-empty string will work fine as it will be casted to boolean automatically
    $message = "whatever";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$var could be `!= ''`  but not`=  ''` eg  .. null

```
  if ($var == ""){
   //do nothing
 } else {
   if (is_null($var) {
     $message ='NULL';
   } else {
     $message = "whatever";
   }

}
```